# How to add auto-incrementing by group (or partition) property .NET Core EF with PostgreSql?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a model as follows:

```
public record Record
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int StructureId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> RecordData { get; set; }
    public int RecordOrder { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make RecordOrder property to auto-increment non-uniquely. Every record needs a unique auto-incrementing ID inside a specific StructureId, because there will be multiple records that are connected to the same Structure. If it is still confusing here is an example:

```
Simple example:
RecordId   StructureId   RecordData   RecordOrder
       1             1   {someData}             1
       2             1   {someData}             2
       3             1   {someData}             3
       4             2   {someData}             1
       5             2   {someData}             2
       6             2   {someData}             3

Somewhat advanced example:
RecordId   StructureId   RecordData   RecordOrder
       1             1   {someData}             1
       2             1   {someData}             2
       3             2   {someData}             1
       4             3   {someData}             1
       5             1   {someData}             3
       6             2   {someData}             2
```

Or maybe you can suggest other ways to do Record ordering and unique ids inside a specific Structure without a need to create new tables for new structures...

P.S. I'm using PosgreSql 14, .NET 5.0, EF Core 5.0.13 and Npgsql if it matters

Comment: That always requires custom code.

Comment: @GertArnold Custom code meaning something like a script in method with the logic that will update database by declaring or changing that Order number every time there is a change to database?

Comment: Like that, yes. There's no standard solution. AFAIK there's not such a concept as nested sequences in Postgresql (or any major db vendor).